# How to find if I have bad breath

Tags: smell, air

I want to check if after eating some kind of food my breath has become bad. In most of these situations I don't feel my breath as bad, because I have used to it and don't find it unpleasant. The problem is I can't smell my own breath. But people I talk to may feel it is bad. 
Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 12):

The trick that I've always used is very simple and doesn't take up much time at all. Simply lick your wrist and wait ten seconds. Now you can just smell your wrist. That's what your breath smells like.

Comment: Does this seriously work? Because if so, I've been doing it wrong all this time!

Comment: @Darren It works for me. Try it, it's not hard at all

Comment: Will definitely try it! Good answer

Comment: Remarkably simple, yet smelly!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to figure out if you have bad breath is to just **"blow in your nose"**.

You simply have to move your lower jaw forward a little so that when you breathe out of your moth the air goes into your nose. Now you fill your mouth with a little bit of air from your lungs, then start breathing in through your nose and pushing the air out of your mouth with your cheeks.

Maybe you have seen a "very cool" smoker one day who does this trick where he has the smoke coming out his mouth and going back in his nose. This is basically the same what you have to do.

**It might take some time to master this**, but once you know how to do it you can check your breath in **very little time** and **without any other equipment**. You can even **do it in public**, as long as you're not really talking to someone, no one will really notice...

Answer (score 1):

**Things to do:**

- Breathe into a cup. Make sure the cup is clean and has no previous obvious odours. Hold the cup over your mouth and nose and breathe into it. After that sniff the inside of the cup and that should give you an indication of how your mouth smells.

  - This may be helpful as a cup can be found in many dining areas.
- Use your hands. Cup your hands over your nose and mouth and breathe into your hands. The smell of your mouth should be obvious once you breathe in through your nose. Make sure your hands don't stink before using them.

***Other Things***

- Possibly helpful [link](http://www.davisanddingle.com/blog/bid/146415/10-ways-to-know-you-have-bad-breath)
- Swab your mouth with a cotton applicator or swab, or even your finger and smell that. Remember though to never put anything dirty in you mouth, so be careful.
- Invest in a [Halimeter](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halimeter) these can detect various oral odours.